# Groovy: Timeduration-Subtraction

Tags: date, groovy, subtraction

I am creating a csv in Groovy and need to get some durations prepared. I am using TimeDuration for that task.

```
Date start = Date.parse('dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm', 04.03.2016 14:30)
Date end   = Date.parse('dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm', 04.03.2016 23:30)
TimeDuration duration = TimeCategory.minus( end, start );
entry  << "${duration.hours}:${duration.minutes}";
```

Everything is fine. Now I create the pause duration:

```
TimeDuration pause;

if(duration.hours >=6 && duration.hours < 8){
  pause = new TimeDuration(0, 0, 30, 0, 0) ;
} else if ( duration.hours >= 8 ) {
  pause = new TimeDuration(0, 0, 45, 0, 0) ;
} else {
  pause = new TimeDuration(0, 0, 0, 0, 0) ;
}

entry  << "${pause.hours}:${pause.minutes}";
entry  << ";";
```

Everything is fine so far. Now I subtract the pause for getting the real worktime:

```
// subtract pause from duration
TimeDuration workTime= duration.minus(pause);
entry  << "${workTime.hours}:${workTime.minutes}";
entry  << ";";
```

For the case I had a duration of 9 hours an 00 minutes, I get a worktime of 9 hours and -45 minutes

```
println entry; // 9:00;0:45;9:-45
```

What I want is to get a worktime of 8:15.

Has anyone any hints?

Answer (score 1):

`TimeDuration` is not intended to be formated. It's only a class to hold a duration and manipulate this duration.

If you want to format such duration, you should use the `toMilliseconds()` method and format this.

For example :

```
entry  << new Date(workTime.toMilliseconds()).format("HH:mm:ss")
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I did this and get now positive minutes, but still the hours are wrong:

    println entry; // 9:00;0:45;9:15

Comment: Don't know why, I have copyied exactly your example and get "08:15:00" at the end. See https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5186766520713216

Comment: Hi Jeremie. You are right. It seems i got a problem with my IDE. I copied my code into my IDE and got the result of my answer again. I will keep you updated what the issue is.